# What Doctype should I use for the marquee tag?

Tags: html

I am validating an HTML website. I have a MARQUEE tag and I would like to know the correct DOCTYPE to use. I am currently using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct Doctype. `<marquee>` is non-standard.

You could [write a custom DTD](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/own-dtd.html), but you are better off not using it in the first place.

It is a horrible piece of code. It is good for solving the problem of displaying a lot of information in a small space, non-interactively — but webpages *are* interactive. So it doesn't solve any problem you have, but it does mean people can't read it at the speed they choose, and its motion makes reading content near it hard (because it is distracting).

Comment: So how can I validate a page that has this tag? Is it possible? Surely it should be... it loads and displays correctly in my browser.

Comment: It is a requirement in my brief... I need to include an effect that starts from one side and exits on the other side. The marquee tag did this very simply. How else can I get this desired effect?

Comment: Shoot whomever gave you the brief. The effect can be achieved with JavaScript though. You just need to dynamically update the style properties via the DOM interface.

Comment: Can you please point me in the right direction to research how to do this? Simply as possible.

Comment: To clarify, my page cited in Quentin’s answer contains a link to a tagsoup DTD, which contains the `marquee` element, so you can use
`<doctype html system "http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/tagsoup.dtd">`
or copy the DTD on your server and use it from there. This would answer the question that was asked. On the other hand, you can alternatively just ignore the error messages about `marquee` (unless you get paid for getting a clean validator report). And using JavaScript instead of `marquee` is probably a better option, if you set up controls for the user.